# Magento 2 importing products with attributes like colors and sizes

Tags: magento, import, attributes, magento2, product

I am creating some products with Python and exporting them in CSV, so they can be imported to Magento 2.

Let's say a product is a t-shirt and it comes in 10 different colors and 10 different sizes.

I was told that there is no way to put all that information in 1 row and that I had to create 1 row for each color and for each size...

So that comes to 10 colors x 10 sizes = 100 different rows for just 1 product! Is this real? Is there not a way on Magento 2 to make attribute columns for "colors" and "sizes" and put the values all together with a separator or something like this Red|Green|Blue and the sizes Small|Large|XLarge etc...?